# VBS Click Position

Tags: vbscript

Is there a way to make a VBScript click in an exact position of your screen like (10,100) or somthing along those lines? Or perhaps click over a text box?

Comment: Hi. If you find an answer helpful, you can click the up vote buttons to the left of the answer, and if the answer was the one you wanted, you can click the big tick to accept. Most forums and sites that give answers have something of this sort, and it is usually a good idea to use these rating systems.

Answer (score 5):

VBScript, by itself, isn't aware of the desktop or any other windows.  Through the use of various COM/ActiveX objects, you can interact with other processes and windows, though.  For example, you can [create a shortcut on the desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [start a program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [automate a series of keystrokes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or [force a program to come to the front](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As far as automating mouse movements or mouse clicks, you would probably need to write your own COM object that can do this.  A combination of the [SetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API calls could accomplish this.

Google Answers has some [example C++ code](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=359697) that can accomplish this.
Planet Source Code has some [example VB6 code](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1530&lngWId=7) that can accomplish this.

From there, you can create your COM/ActiveX objects that will allow you to use VBScript to click where you want.

Comment: Well I dont know either of those, could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Whats COM? ActiveX I know involves one of it being Internet Explorer, but COM, and the rest of ActiveX?

Comment: The short answer is that VBScript cannot really do what you are asking.  Perhaps the more important question is, why do you need to use VBScript to click on the screen?

Comment: Auto Login on a site called "Roblox". I know it sounds stupid but, you get 1 currency for someone going to one of your places. And if I make a loop of this that goes hours, I get a lot of the currency.

Comment: With VBScript, any time you use CreateObject(), you are using COM.  If you are interested in learning about COM, you should consider studying VB.NET or C#.

Comment: In that case, you will probably want to go with a program like http://www.autohotkey.com/  Programs like this will allow you to automate a bunch of keystrokes, mouse movements or mouse clicks.

Comment: So are you saying its not possible for VBScript to click in an exact point, or viewing a textbox while mouse is hovering over it? Just clicking in an exact position is all I really need.

Comment: Correct.  VBScript cannot do this, by itself.  You either need something else that VBScript can use to do this - such as a COM object - or you need to use a utility like AutoHotKey.  There's plenty of programs out there that will do this each with a variety of features.  You'll just need to find one that works for you.  http://www.google.com/search?q=automate+mouse+clicks

Comment: Ill give that program a try, but will you tell me a bit about it?

Comment: I downloaded the program but how do I do loops and stuff?

Comment: You'll need to read over the documentation.  They provide documentation specifically for loops (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) and some general examples (http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm).  Beyond that you will need to discuss it on their forum (http://www.autohotkey.com/support/).  Remember, that is not the only program that can do what you want.  There are plenty of them out there.  Play around with a few of them and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 3):

This will move the cursor:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Excel, x, y

Set Excel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

x = "500"
y = "222"
Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro ( _
    "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ""," & x & "," & y & ")")

WScript.Sleep (100)
WScript.Echo "Program Ended"
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below can be used to move your mouse to x,y coords 100,100

```
Set DeviceReplay = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")

DeviceReplay.MouseMove 100,100
```